# Preventing XSS attacks in Jersey with XML Content-Type

Tags: xml, security, jakarta-ee, jersey-2.0

I am having Jersey REST service with Content-Type as JSON. For this I have used AntiSamy to filter XSS attacks.

Now I need to support XML Content-Type, AntiSamy considers XML as a threat and all my requests are thrown as attack.

How to support XML as a Content-Type and avoid XSS attacks (filtering)? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since AntiSamy doesn't help with XML, I went with regex based validation.

Jersey Bean validation will not work here. Used ESAPI encoder and canonicalized the input and validated with regex as mentioned in http://java.dzone.com/articles/stronger-anti-cross-site

Instead of a normal filter went with Jersey ContainerRequestFilter.